# How to make rest call return all results, or the the total count (Sharepoint REST API)

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, visual-studio-2013

I need to know the total number of results for a query, the code below works for 100 items, but when I change it to 1000 I get a 500 Internal Server error, because this is sharepoint online I suppose they might have some kind of protection to avoid very large responses that might hang the servers if you allow this to every tenant.

I guess that I would have to iterate over all results until I get the count.

Can anyone tell me how can I iterate over all results until I get the total count?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Sites");

        string user=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
        string pass = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
        char[] passwordChars = pass.ToCharArray();
        SecureString password = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in passwordChars)
        {
            password.AppendChar(c);
        }

        foreach (var key in config.Keys)
        {
            Uri siteUri = new Uri(config.GetValues(key as string)[0]);
            using (var context = new ClientContext(siteUri.ToString()))
            {
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(user, password);

                string fullurl = siteUri + "/_api/search/query?querytext='pptx'&rowlimit=100";               
                HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(fullurl);
                endpointRequest.Credentials = context.Credentials;

                endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
                endpointRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
                endpointRequest.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry";
                endpointRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED: f");
                HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
                // process response..
                XDocument oDataXML = XDocument.Load(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream(), LoadOptions.None);
                XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";
                XNamespace d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";
                XNamespace m = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata";

                List<XElement> items = oDataXML.Descendants(d + "query")
                                 .Elements(d + "PrimaryQueryResult")
                                 .Elements(d + "RelevantResults")
                                 .Elements(d + "Table")
                                 .Elements(d + "Rows")
                                 .Elements(d + "element")
                                 .ToList();

                // N.B. there might be a more elegant/efficient way of extracting the values from the (slightly awkward) XML than this.. 
                var searchResults = from item in items
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        Title = item.Element(d + "Cells").Descendants(d + "Key").First(a => a.Value == "Title").Parent.Element(d + "Value").Value,
                                        Author = item.Element(d + "Cells").Descendants(d + "Key").First(a => a.Value == "Author").Parent.Element(d + "Value").Value,
                                        HitHighlightedSummary = item.Element(d + "Cells").Descendants(d + "Key").First(a => a.Value == "HitHighlightedSummary").Parent.Element(d + "Value").Value,
                                        Path = item.Element(d + "Cells").Descendants(d + "Key").First(a => a.Value == "Path").Parent.Element(d + "Value").Value
                                    };

                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Run at:{0}, Count:{1}",DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(), items.Count);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint REST Search response contains element `/query/PrimaryQueryResult/RelevantResults/TotalRows` that returns the total results count.

### Example

You could use the following LINQ-to-XML to return `TotalRows` element value:

```
var totalResultsCount = oDataXML.Descendants(XName.Get("TotalRows", d.ToString())).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: if i have a rowlimit set to 5, will TotalRows be 5 or be the total rows if there were no limit (e.g., 1027)?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly i don't think you need to iterate the entire query to get the count. Simply call .Count() on your query.  I am not exactly sure from your example which part you are trying to get the count for.  However, as an example just add this line after you create your searchResults query:

```
var count = searchResults.Count();
```

Comment: this only returns 10 items but the true is there are 520 results.

Comment: the search rest api allows to limit the nr of returned results, with the screenshot below you can see I can set maximum 500, if there are more than 500 items that means I have to page the results and in some way get the total count. http://screencast.com/t/CxcupexcGjG